# Does Temporal Logic have undecidable propositions?

Tags: logic

In order to avoid being too broad or ill defined let me preface by stating that by a proposition in temporal logic I mean a proposition which uses modal operators (until,next,...). In atemporal logic the truth value of a proposition $P$ in a variable $x$ is either true, false or undecidable and remains the same. In temporal logic the truth value of our proposition $P$ changes with time so even in the case $P$ is true or false at the current time it's truth value may be subject to change. My intuition tells me that regardless of the type of logic we are doing, an undecidable proposition is and always will be undecidable. One Answer I got said that since time changes everything the truth values of said propositions will also change I.e an undecidable proposition may be decidable at a past or future point. This answer was too "soft" but it makes sense. Any fairly rigorous elucidation of the question in the title would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In formal first-order logic a sentence is either true or false with respect to an interpretation of the language in a model, and either provable or not provable with respect to a collection of axioms for the language.  A "fairly rigorous elucidation" would require a formalization of axioms for Temporal Logic (presumably as a species of modal logic).  Can you reference such a formalization?

Comment: According to [Enya](https://youtu.be/7wfYIMyS_dI), only time can say that hardly decidable propositions are true of false. So, perhaps you're on the right track.